# Order estimates question and big O notation

Tags: asymptotics

How can I show that $y(x) = 1 - \cos(x)$ is $\mathcal{O}(x^2)$ for $|x| <<1$ ?

Additionally, with the $|x| << 1$ is there a precise definition? I tried to google it but nothing conclusive returned. I'm assuming it just means $x \to 0$. Is there any reason for the $|x| <<$ term to use the number $1$? Or is it just a matter of convetion.

Would you say that $\cos(x) \leq x$ in this case, or use a strict inequality as $x \to 0$ and $x \neq 0$

Is it sufficient to do the following:

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-cos(x)}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x} \neq 0$

Comment: $|x| << 1$ means usually much smaller than $1$ and yes, it is not a very precise notation.

Comment: Yes, I was familiar that it meant "much smaller" but was wanting to know if I was missing out on something more precise. That will do, however, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that $f(x)$ is of $ \mathcal O(g(x))$ for $x\rightarrow 0$, one has to show that, for a constant, $|C|<\infty$, the following holds: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{}{}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=C.$$

In words: $f(x)$ tends to somewhere in the Order of $g(x)$ when $x$ tends to the same number or even $\pm \infty$. This is "big  Oh" if the quotient above tends to a constant, and it is "little oh" if the quotient tends to $0$.
In our case
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(x)}{2x}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
(Where the L'Hospital rule was used.)

Comment: L'hospitals, the missing batter of all fried problems. Ingenius!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Just re-living a silly way my late professor used to say thanks to us, apologies for the confusion.
Thank you for the assistance, zoli!

Comment: But, what is "batter"? That I don't know. Please, help to understand.

Comment: "one has to show" is incorrect - it should say "one can show" or "it is sufficient to show".  One can have $f = O(g)$ without the limit of $f/g$ existing.

Answer (score 1):

> > How can I show that $y(x) = 1 - \cos(x)$ is $\mathcal{O}(x^2)$ for $|x| <<1$ ?

**Hint.** Recall the Maclaurin series, which says that for any function $f \in \mathcal{C}^2(-a,a)$ you have, as $x \to 0$,
$$
f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2!}+\int_0^x (x-t)^{2}f^{(2)}(t)dt.
$$ Then applying it to $x \longmapsto \cos x$ you readily obtain
$$
\cos (x)=\cos (0)-\sin (0)\:x-\cos''(0)\frac{x^2}{2}-\int_0^x (x-t)^{2}\cos(t)dt
$$ (*alternately you may just integrate the preceding integral twice by parts*) and since
$$
\left|\int_0^x (x-t)^{2}\cos(t)dt\right|\leq \int_0^x (x-t)^{2}|\cos(t)|dt\leq \int_0^x (x-t)^{2}dt=\frac{x^3}{3}
$$ you get, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\cos (x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}(x^3)=1+\mathcal{O}(x^2).
$$